# Get a file with non english characters in the name with copy() or file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I'm trying to grab a file and then save it to the server folder in this way:

```
copy('http://domain.name/image-with-ø-symbol.jpg', $local_path);
```

or:

```
file_put_contents($local_path, file_get_contents('http://domain.name/image-with-ø-symbol.jpg'));
```

But ø symbol caused this error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents('http://domain.name/image-with-Гё-symbol.jpg'): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

So it converted from 'ø' to 'Гё' somehow, however if I'm trying to display this jpg name or write this name to the database this non-english character displayed correctly. How to force this functions to use correct encoding?

Comment: If you encode the url, it works? `http://domain.name/image-with-%C3%B8-symbol.jpg`

Comment: Character set mismatch. You've likely entered the URL in an editor set to UTF8, but the error message is displaying in a single-byte encoding like ISO8859-1 and that's probably what the filename expects as well.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte thanks for the point, solved by urlencode().

Comment: No problem. I've wrote an answer for this.

Comment: @Felippe Duarte, accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some URL Encode (like `urlencode()`) function to get the correct value:

`http://domain.name/image-with-%C3%B8-symbol.jpg`